# QML iterating through model

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to draw the content of a ListModel to a canvas in QML. The content of this model is displayed in a ListView elsewhere in the application, so I know the model is correctly filled with content.

No I am trying to update the canvas every time the model data changes:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQml.Models 2.2

Item {
    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: canvas

        onPaint: {
            console.log("onPaint()")
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

            console.log(particleListModel.count)
            for(var i = 0; i < particleListModel.count; i++) {
                console.log(i)
            }
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: particleListModel

        onDataChanged: {
            console.log("data changed")
            canvas.requestPaint()
        }
    }
}
```

Once I change the data (in C++) I receive the `dataChanged()` signal and the `onPaint()` of the canvas gets called. However the debug output of

```
console.log(particleListModel.count)
```

is "undefined".

How can this be, while the regular ListView is able to display the content correctly?

Comment: shouldn't you use "rowCount" instead of "count"?

Comment: Thank you! Calling row count as a function `rowCount()` solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with the Model you need to call the `rowCount` function instead of `count` since the latter is a property of the `ListView` and not of the model.

The following should work:

```
console.log(particleListModel.rowCount())
```